# jquery validate plugin errors

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I'm using jquery validate plugin for my form.
 the code for my validation is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#registration").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                maxlength: 15
            },
            email: {
            required:true
            },

        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            $.each(this.successList, function (index, value) {
                $(value).css({ "border-color": "green" });
                return $(value).popover("hide");
            });
            return $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
                $(value.element).css({ "border-color": "red" });
                var _popover;
                console.log(value.message);
                _popover = $(value.element).popover({
                    trigger: "manual",
                    placement: "top",
                    content: value.message,
                    template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow \"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
                });
                _popover.data("bs.popover").options.content = value.message;
                return $(value.element).popover("show");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the problem with the code is ,the name field is getting validated but my email field is not getting validated.
can anyone help

Comment: Not a solution but something to bear in mind, html5 provides a lot of this, using <input type="email" required />  would solve your email needs without js at all

Comment: i would like to display my validation messages as custom popovers

Comment: Could you also add the HTML form?